# How to Remove "user_data" and ".php" from Website Page Link?

Tags: php, url, content-management-system

I have this new page: Events Calendar. Presently, the URL is:

```
www.domainname.com/user_data/eventscalendar.php
```

How can I remove the "user_data" and the ".php"?

I am using EC Cube CMS and I cannot find anything about this on the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess rewrite rules with mod_rewrite module of apache enabled.

Learn about it here if you are new to rewrite rules,

http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/